# В POST-запрос добавить id

Tags: jquery, php

Запрос на jquery выглядит так

---

```
<script>
function post(){
$.post("pages/comment.php?id=<?echo$row['id'];?>", { text<?echo$row['id'];?>: $("#text<?echo$row['id'];?>").val() },
   function(data) {
if(data != "ok"){
 $("#error_error").html("<div class=\"alert alert-error\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\">×</a>"+data+"</div>");   
     }else{
         location.replace("/articles.php?id=<?echo$row['id'];?>");
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

---

Файл обработчик

---

```
require_once '../system/core.php';
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `moderation`='1'"));
$text=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['text']));
if (empty($text))
{
echo 'Не введён текст комментария!';
exit;
}
if (mb_strlen($text) < 2 || mb_strlen($text) > 1000)
{
echo 'Недопустимая длина текста комментария';
exit;
}
//если нет ошибок - пишем в базу
mysql_query("UPDATE `articles` SET `comments` = '".intval($row['comments']+1)."' WHERE `id` = '".$row['id']."'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `articles_comments` SET `id_user` = '".$user['id']."', `id_articles` = '".$row['id']."', `text` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."', `time` = '".$realtime."'");
$rating_user = $user['rating']+0.05;
if($user['rating']<$setup['rating'])mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `rating`='".$rating_user."' WHERE `id`='".$user['id']."'");
echo "ok";
```

---

Форма

---

```
echo '<div id="error_error"></div>';
echo '<textarea id="text'.$row['id'].'" rows="5" placeholder="Введите ваш комментарий"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="blue" value="Добавить комментарий" onclick="post()"><br/>';
```

---

Так вот, нужно как-то в post-запрос добавить ид статьи. На одной странице у меня выводится некоторое кол-во статей. К каждой статье есть комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

```
function post(){
  //пример для последних версий jquery
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pages/comment.php",
      data: { id: <?php echo $row['id'] ?> }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      //html контейнер на странице, куда ты хочешь поместить ответ
      $('#comments').html(data);
    });
}
```

итого, функция аджаксом отправляет данные на скрипт и ожидает от него ответ, который помещает в контейнер c id="comments", соответственно обрабатывающий php скрипт должен быть отдельным файлом, который должен выводить ответ в html формате.

По большому счету счету весь ответ сервера было бы правильно перевести в json и пользоваться им на клиентской стороне для обработки ошибочных сообщений и тд

Comment: Что именно нужно дописать в обработчик?
В ту функцию добавил $("#comments").html(data).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800); чтобы исчезало сообщение об ошибке.

И всегда показывается надпись что не введен текст комментария.

Comment: Сделал так:

<script>
function post()
{
//Получаем параметры
var text = $('#text').val();
//выводим информацию об отправке данных
$("#load").fadeIn('slow');
// Отсылаем параметры
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "pages/comment.php?id=<?echo$row['id'];?>",
data: "text="+text,
// Выводим то что вернул PHP
success: function(html){
$("#result").append(html);
$("#result").slideDown('slow');
$("#result").text(html).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
// Убираем информацию об отправке данных
$("#load").fadeOut('slow');
}
});
}
</script>

Но пока не обновлю страницу комментарий не появится.

Comment: функция, вызываемая в случае удачного ответа сервера это callback который должен срабатывать автоматически, если этого не происходит, значит, что-то не так в коде, пробуйте дебажить.
Cтруктура следующая - скрипт, выводит список старых комментов и форму добавления новых. Второй скрипт обрабатывает запросы на добавление комментариев и отправляет положительный или отрицательный ответ.
На странице со списком комментов javascript делает запросы ко второму скрипту и обрабатывает его ответы, в нашем случае добавляет содержимое ответа в нужный контейнер на странице.

Comment: i.e. коммент пользователя был "Круто", javascript вытащил id пользователя, передал его с текстом коммента в php второму скрипту, который записывает его в БД и возвращает ответ типа {errors: false; comment: 'Круто'; author: 'Вася', time: '02.11.12'}, javascript получает этот ответ (в моем примере в методе done()) и читает полученный json, проверяет наличие ошибок (data.errors). В случае наличия ошибки тело ошибки записывается в контейнер ошибок  $('#errors').text(data.errors). В случае отсутствия ошибок формируется блок коммента и добавляется к общему списку комментов.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: И как это применить?

Comment: И в моем случае комментарии добавляются с обновлением страницы. Как этого избежать?